# Manifold $X$ in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ with $c_1(X)=0$ admits arbitrarily small deformations which are Moishezon?

Tags: complex-geometry, deformation-theory

It is known that any Calabi-Yau manifold $X$, i.e. compact Kähler manifold with $c_1(X)=0$, has arbitrarily small deformations which are algebraic (see, for example, [Buchdahl's paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-007-0168-6), Proposition 5).

Note that manifolds in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ are bimeromorphic to compact Kähler manifolds, and Moishezon manifolds are bimeromorphic to projective manifolds, so do we have:

Any manifold $X$ in Fujiki class $\mathcal C$ with $c_1(X)=0$ admits arbitrarily small deformations which are Moishezon manifolds?